# Custom Font & Icon on Button in Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I'm trying to get e Menu inside my fragment a little more custom. The Code does some resizing on the Button-Symbol which I created (is there by the way any better solution for this?) the Text & Font of the Button are also customized.

The Code runs in a Standalone Activity, running it in a Fragment doesn't work anymore:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,true);
    final Button events = view.findViewById(R.id.events);
    // BUTTON FONT THEME
    String etext = "<font color=#FFFFFF>NEXT</font> <font color=#8def00> EVENTS </font>";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        events.setText(Html.fromHtml(etext, 0)); // for 24 api and more
    } else {
        events.setText(Html.fromHtml(etext)); // or for older api
    }
    events.setTypeface(ralewayfont);
    Drawable iconevents =   ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_calendar);
    int WIconCal = iconevents.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int HIconCal = iconevents.getIntrinsicHeight();
    iconevents.setBounds(0,0,WIconCal/3,HIconCal/3);
    events.setCompoundDrawables(iconevents, null, null, null);
}
```

It doesn't give me any errors - it doesn't resize the Images and doesn't set the custom font on the Buttons.

Comment: Try to use color='value' with simple apostrophes... else you changing the colors, not the font

Comment: Second, the bounds of intrinsic drawables are set on the TextView not the drawable (unless you want to resize the image but for that you redraw it scaled)

Answer (score 0):

You should make more layout files that target specific API versions. In your case, I would make a `/res/layout-v24/fragment_main.xml` and set your v24-specific button attributes there. No need to do all the stuff your doing in your code snippet. Just inflate the layout like you are doing, connect your button with findViewById(), and Android OS will automatically know to use the layout-v24 version if it detects a phone using v24 or higher. Anything below v24 will use your default `/res/layout/fragment_main.xml`.

Hope that helps!